# Geckofx with non ui app

Tags: c#, webkit, geckofx

I'm new to geckofx, and wonder if i can use it in non ui app like windows console or just a web service. It will be run background to get html content?

I've been using web-browser but cannot stop it from popping up new windows.

Also, any idea to do the same with [webkit2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkit2net/), it has no documentation and sample code at all but it seems to be what i need most since it's isolated from UI process which i don't need. Unfortunately, it requires Apple Application Support installed which i cannot accept it.

Comment: GeckoFx doesn't need to be on-screen, but it does need an event pump (see answer talking about Application.DoEvents() below). Have you ruled out using something easier to get html content, like  System.Net.WebClient?

Comment: thanks 4 your reply, i do know how to use webclient, but it can't catch the ajax content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it calling the `CreateControl` method.

```
GeckoWebBrowser obj = new GeckoWebBrowser();
obj.CreateControl();
```

Apparently, calling `CreateControl` forces the handle to be created, so all can work as if it were inside a visible window.

Also, you may have to call `Application.DoEvents` a couple of times, mostly after you demand the browser to do something.